# Use bitwise operation for query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, bitwise-operators, nosql

I need to make query like this in MongoDB:

```
db.collection.find( { $where : "(this.type & some_num) ^ some_num == 0"} )
```

Some_num is a variable and it can be any integer.

I read the doc at [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand)  which says Javascript query slows down execution and also it cannot use an index and requires a table scan.

What is the alternative to the above query?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this query?

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do in Mongo is to store the calculated value that you plan to search on in a field and then create an index on it.  Otherwise, you are pretty much doomed to scanning the whole collection.

Answer (score 1):

$where must be slow.

It would be better something like $bitand, but it is not implemented yet. see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3518.

Possible solution (for me) was using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard for me to understand what exactly are you trying to achieve with this query. Construct this.type is not valid in JS, so I assume that you are trying to get a field type from your current document. Then for some reason you are doing bitwise & with some variable. And then finally you are xoring the result with the same variable.

Either I am interpreting this wrong, or you are doing something really strange.

Anyway, you will be able to use [bitwise xor operator in mognodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/bit/#up._S_bit) 2.6 or you can try the experimental version 2.5 now.

Comment: Actually, I nedd to use bitwise operator to make query. [bitwise xor operator in mognodb 2.6](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/bit/#up._S_bit) allow to use bitwise operation for update only.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I gave to you. It will be only available in 2.6. There is no other way to do it in 2.4 version.